Phase Slope Distance Calcuation
After trying to implement IFFT algorithms for phase-based ranging, as outlined in this very interesting and descriptive blog post; I've been getting horrendous results (orders of magnitude inaccurate), and this led me to go back to step one. I tried calculating a simple phase slope to get the distance, the one from the example in the blog post.

A quick estimate of the slope would give you $\frac{6\pi}{80\cdot10^{6}}$, distance would be $d=\frac{c}{4\pi}\cdot\frac{6\pi}{80\cdot10^{6}}=5.625$
Issue is, the blog post clearly outlines that ground truth distance is $9.9$ meters. Did the blog post just put the wrong diagram or am I simply implementing the steps wrong?

@Hilmar Wait, how does that increase to value of R? The formula is:
$R=\frac{c}{4\pi}\cdot slope$
What you described would cause a smaller $slope$, which would decrease the value of $R$, which I calculated with a glance to be ~$5.625$. How did you get $R=10.875m$.

The author of that blog post is also active here so will hopefully see this. Have you also tried to comment on the post directly?

@HysanHappy: oops, I got it wrong, so I delete my comment

This looks like the negative of the unwrapped phase.  Isn't this the phase behavior of a real-time FIR filter with a pretty clear delay (that is proportional to the slope of the phase)?   I think the phase should be a negative slope for a delay that is a positive value as you get with any causal filter.

@robertbristow-johnson I think the author willingly made the data positive so it's not too confusing. You are right that it would normally be a negative slope after the phase is unwrapped, it is in my measurements.
But as there is not such thing as a negative distance, I don't think this matters too much.

" I don't think this matters too much." - - - - - - It matters regarding confusion.  The purpose of displaying these graphs is to communicate something to other people.  The actual phase is the negative of what you displayed.  You're communicating a piece of misinformation.  You want to communicate information.  (Unless you're deliberately wanting to disinform, which I presume you're not.)

@HysanHappy Are you interested in a similar method that is more accurate? It's a little more complex but still uses the same principle of transmitting multiple pulses at different frequencies and using the returns together to yield a fine range resolution.

@Envidia You mean RTT/ToF?

@HysanHappy If you're referring to round-trip and time-of-flight, yes, however it additionally uses multiple pulses at different frequencies to increase the effective bandwidth of the returns, resulting in a fine range resolution. The method allows you to use hardware that only needs to sample the bandwidth of a simple pulse, but gets you a higher range resolution once processing is complete.

The section from which this figure is taken describes a one-way communication scenario where it was clearly stated that "The Tx sends a CW at each of these 80 subchannels while the Rx downconverts and measures the phase for each such frequency". Also, the first frequency shown is $2.401$ GHz while the last is $2.48$ GHz. Therefore, the range comes out to be
$$
d \approx \frac{c}{2\pi}\cdot \frac{16.5}{79e6} = 9.97 ~\text{m}
$$
A 2-way scenario where the phase appears with constant $4\pi$ comes afterwards. Now I have explicitly mentioned this before the phase expression to avoid any misunderstanding.
Also, you mentioned that you're getting wrong results by orders of magnitude. When we talk about the fastest thing on earth, it is light that is a form of electromagnetic wave. At such speeds ($3\times 10^8$ m/s), a small error in measurement causes a large error in distance. For example, a 1 $\mu$s error can result in a range error of 300 m. This will keep things in perspective when you perform ranging experiments later.

Wow, thanks for answering, as the original source yourself! This does answer my question.
My issue with getting wrong results is that from a graphical view, the phase plot looks good. In the same way, the IFFT gives proper looking peaks. The estimate of the phase slope method and IFFT are consistently $\pm 1 meter$ from each other. But the estimate is not at all close to the real life distance.
I'm hoping this is a measurement related error.
